# How do I get data from user input with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to have a have the user input a name to check against a list of names, however I am not sure how to store the user input to be used in the whitelist function. I tried using if e in whitelist: but it does not work, what should I put in my if clause? Or is there another solution

```
from tkinter import Message
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

#Excel sheet being used
book = load_workbook('Desktop\python\excel.xlsx')
#Active sheet
sheet = book['names']

whitelist = set(row[0].value for row in sheet.rows)

#User input name to check for whitelist
e = Entry(root, width=20)
e.pack()


#Condition to check if user is whitelisted
def whitelist():
    if e in whitelist:
        print("User is whitelisted")
    else:
        print("The user is not whitelisted")

button = Button(root, text="Check", command=whitelist)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are using the name `whitelist` for both a function and a set.  It can only refer to one of those things at a time.

Comment: The code works now after the edit, thank you for your help!

Comment: Do not edit the question with the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for an input field when a button is pressed by using the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def checker(input):
    if input == "Hello":
        print("Hello")
    else:
        print("Not Hello")


#Create window
root.title("Hello World")
root.geometry("200x100")
#Create an entry input and a button that checks for the input
button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=lambda: checker(entry.get()))
button.pack()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
#RUN LOOP
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just tried this and it prints not hello, thanks for helping me find the problem!

Comment: @KappaCheeno Note that it is case sensitive